# Cannot read property 'player' of undefined

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am working on a angular+nativescript app. In which I want to embed some videos from Youtube and Dailymotion. I found only one plugin to do that which is:

https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-youtubeplayer

I followed the exact documentation but still getting the error:

```
Cannot read property 'player' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is very common when you add a plugin that has a native dependency, it is not linked properly during livesync (here an Android SDK I guess). Usually this solves the problem:

`$ rm -rf platforms node_modules`

`$ tns run android`

Comment: Didn't work. Now I am removing this plugin and going for webview. When i use webview, youtube player's fullscreen option gets disabled. Do you know about that?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was using an older version.
When I read the documentation I just run `tns plugin add nativescript-youtubeplayer` - that installed the 2.2.6 version even though my nativescript was 6.x and that wasn't the latest version.

So I just forced the latest: `tns plugin add nativescript-youtubeplayer@latest` - and that solved it for me ..

Comment: I have moved my app to flutter and would suggest the same to anyone who is happy with nativescript in terms of performance and community support.

Comment: Welcome. Sorry for a typo in my comment. I wanted to say 'not happy' some how skipped 'not'. Lol